# What should I fix in my settings in PSpice for simulation?

Tags: flipflop, pspice, error, nand

I am trying to build a D flip-flop from CMOS NAND gates.

This is the CMOS circuit to be built with NAND gates:

[image]

I can simulate NAND gate logic like this, and it works:

1 0 = 1,
0 1 = 1,
0 0 = 1,
1 1 = 0

Next I connected a 4 NAND gate block to be a D flip-flop:

[image]

But I can't simulate because of this error:

[image]

Comment: You probably need to suply an appropriate `.model` card for the `MBREAK`. Check the PSpice manual to see what default settings it has and how it influences your design. It might also help to add some series resistances in there, maybe it will help the solver.

Comment: I tried to set MBREAK to .model Mbreakp PMOS W=30u L=1u
and .model Mbreakn PMOS W=10u L=1u .It's doesn't worked and put series resistances at Q and Qbar of D flip-flop before conected in2 nandgate_3 and in1 nandgate_1

Comment: I'm talking about `Vto, Gamma, Kp, ...`. Width/height are also needed but, mostly the ones that set the MOSFET's characteristics. Maybe you have some in the database. If not, see cmosedu.com or the likes for models.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It's worked.